# How to configure python path for spark worker in the standalone mode?

Tags: apache-spark

I am a newbie to Spark trying to set up a standalone cluster manually. So far both the master and the slave are running well, but when I ran a test application, I got an error saying that the slave cannot find the Python path (this application run without an issue on local mode):

"most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 112, < Slave IP>, executor 0): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Users/xxx/venv/deep_learning/bin/python": error=2, No such file or directory", where **/Users/xxx/venv/deep_learning/bin/python** is the Python used in the **master**.

My question is how I configure Spark so that the slave can recognize the correct Python path? Thanks!

Below is my slave environment in the .bashrc file:

```
export SPARK_HOME=/usr/lib/spark/spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: did you install python/anaconda on the slaves? you need to provide the correct path to the python installation on the slaves.

Comment: Yes, I installed anaconda on the slave. How do I provide the correct path on the slave? I tried export PYTHONPATH=/home/xxx/anaconda3/bin/python:$PYTHONPATH, but it does not work.

Comment: try putting them in `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh`?

Comment: I tried that but still got the same error. Thanks though. Now I suspect the issue might be related to the Jupyter notebook. Currently my notebook is running on http://127.0.0.1/. Perhaps I should modify it to run on the Spark master IP. I will give that a try.